# Shell Script (not bash) : How to redirect script into su root?

Tags: shell, alpine-linux, wsl-2

Regarding `su root -c '/some/foo/command' <<<'somepass'`, we can't use string input redirection in shell (not bash) env.

My box is alpine on WSLv2, so security isn't an issue as it's a windows + WSLv2 dev box. The script can't be run with bash, as it's a /etc/profile.d/*.sh scripts, that run before user login and always use shell instead of bash, so I can't change the way it use bash, is there any possibility to pass the password to the input without using a flat file like in bash, or is there anyway to force /etc/profile.d/*.sh scripts run with bash instead of normal shell script interpreter?

Comment: Can you do: `su root -c 'bash -c  "/some/foo/command <<< \"somepass\""'` ? Obviously quoting is a mess, but it lets you use bash to execute the command with redirection.

Comment: @glennjackman Hello thanks for replying, I tried but it doesn't work sadly, only accept binary, I don't know why alpine WSL run it differently :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just asking how to do a herestring when the shell you are using does not support herestrings, then:

```
su root -c '/some/foo/command' << EOF
somepass
EOF
```

I can't write this response without at least remarking that passing a password this way is not secure.

Comment: what wait, what is the different between <<< and << ? Why I found a lot of <<<EOF rather than <<EOF? (I know we can change EOF to anything we want to), but what is the differences between 2 or 3 character? @William Pursell?

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto With `<<<` you have a "herestring"; the string to the right of `<<<` becomes the input to the command.  With a heredoc (`<<`), the string to the right of the operator is the delimiter; all the text between the heredoc marker and the next occurrence of the delimiter by itself on a line is used as the input.

Comment: I see, seems a lot of stack overflow answer made mistake that put <<<abc as heredoc. Thank you, your answer works for me and it clarify everything that I'm questioning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, if I understand your question correctly.

##### Option 1:  Use `wsl.exe` to run as root without password

First, as a bit of a "hackaround" on WSL, there's *probably* no reason to need to enter the password in the first place.  As long as you have WSL's Windows Interop feature enabled (which it is by default), you can simply call the `wsl.exe` command from *within* WSL to elevate the user to root using something like:

```
wsl.exe ~ -u root -e /some/foo/command
```

No password is needed in this case.  As you said, since this is WSL, the security model of the *Windows* user is what is enforced.

This form assumes, of course, that the script:

1. Has a shebang pointing to the correct shell/interpreter
2. Is set with the executable bit

If there's no shebang line, and you need to specify the shell or interpreter which should run the script, you can use something like:

```
wsl.exe ~ -u root -e bash -lic /some/foo/command
```

Explanation of the arguments:

- `~` is good practice with WSL to set a common starting directory of the user's (in this case, root's) home directory.  It must be the first argument after the `wsl.exe` command.
- `-u` (`--user`), of course, specifies the user in the WSL distribution to run as
- `-e` (`--exec`) is the executable to run in place of, or as, the shell.  For instance, `wsl.exe -e ps -efH` (when nothing else is running) will run *just* the `ps` command with no "owning" process/shell.
- `bash -l` treats it as a login shell, so that your profile is sourced at startup.  Without this, you may be missing necessary environment variables or other configuration for your command.  However, if you *don't* need it for that command, leave it off, since not sourcing your profile will likely improve the execution speed.
- `bash -i` is the same as above, but for "interactive" shells, so that your rc file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) is sourced.  Again, leave it off if unneeded, which is likely won't be for a `root` executed script.
- `bash -c` is, of course, the command string to run in the shell.

##### Option 2:  Pass the password to `sudo`

Per [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/67766/1210833), use `sudo -S` to accept the password from standard input.

##### (Possible) Option 3:  expect

I was thinking about this last night in a similar context, and I believe `expect` can be used for this type of situation.  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet for my use-case.  For your case, of course, the first two options are almost certainly easier and more robust.

But keep `expect` in your toolbelt for other possible scenarios like this.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but your way of doing thing isn't what I'm looking for, as I don't want to use sudo, and I won't login as root as default when I run my WSL. but it do give a certain workaround, but not close.